# C# excuting cmd commands is very slow

Tags: c#, cmd, scripting, udp, port

I want to run a "cmd" command with C# for getting all open ports in my computer.
Firstly I don't know why `IPGlobalProperties` not show all open ports and sockets like `udp` ports.

For getting all ports and sockets I used `netstat` command in C# with `ProcessInfo`.
And for some reasons I want to run my application for multiple times.

When I run the app firstly it works fast and its OK. But after run it in multiple times it goes slowly.

For example, when I run it for the fifth time it does Processafter several minutes!

Here is part of my code:

```
Port = 9999;

ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
Process Process;

List<int> openPorts = new List<int>();
Repeat:

ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + "netstat -an | find " + "\"" + Port + "\"");
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);

StreamReader reader = Process.StandardOutput;
string result = reader.ReadLine();

Process.Kill();
Process.WaitForExit();

if (result.Contains(networkPort.ToString()))
{
    openPorts.Add(networkPort);
    Port++;

    goto Repeat;
}

dosomething();
```

Does anybody know why?

I Only want a list of all open socket and ports in my computer.

It's not matter how i get it , with C# itself or cmd, I just want it to be fast.

How can i do that ?

Comment: You should steer clear of trying to get information from something via cmd. As you experienced, it will be slow and you will have to work with "dirty" output. I would recommend looking at System.Net.NetworkInformation. There are lots of useful tools in there that will help you.

Comment: Also, avoid using `goto`in C#, use instead one of the loops sintaxes (`do...while`, `while`, `for`, `foreach`)

Comment: Your problem, apart from not programming, is that you shell two processes each time you run it. And only one exits. See `cmd /?`. `CMD` is unnecessary completely.

Comment: Can you explain more please ? @CatCat

Comment: Every time you start CMD.exe and ask it to remain running (`/k`), then ask CMD to start NetStat. Just start NetStat.

Answer (score 0):

So, this won't answer your question, but it might lead you in the right direction. This code will give you all the used ports:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var props = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    var conns = props.GetActiveTcpConnections();

    foreach (var conn in conns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((conn.LocalEndPoint.Port));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Tanks But it's not my answer. I used this way before ! It just show `TCP` ports.  But it not show all open ports like `UDP`. And when you enter `netstat` command it show you more.

Comment: Fair enough, how about "var conns = props.GetActiveUdpListeners();" ?

Comment: Again, it's not all the OPEN ports, but I'm sure you can start there. There should be a way to get all the used ones?